# Is there a way to create and populate a Sybase table column with column names based on rows in another table?

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, sap-ase

Is there a way to pivot a Sybase Attribute-Value table, into an Attribute-per-column result set. Can this be done?

**Source table:**

```
| attribute | value |
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| a1        | A1    |
| b2        | BB2   |
| random    | X     |
```

For simplicity, assume `varchar(255)` on both `attribute` and `value` columns, unique index on `attribute`; and the attribute names are 100% *guaranteed* to be strings which are valid Sybase column names.

**Desired select result:**

```
| a1   | b2   | random |
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| A1   | BB2  | X      |
```

**Is this possible to do via SQL in Sybase ASE? (12 or 15)?**

NOTES:

- Just to be clear: *we do NOT know beforehand what the set of attributes is!!!*
- There is no need to persist the result set beyond a #temp pound table.
- The limitation is that there is no Java enabled.

---

<sub>It seems to me that this is impossible to do, since Sybase 15 ASE docs indicate that column names in `ALTER TABLE` must not contain dynamic data:</sub>

> <sub>**computed_column_expression**
>
>   is any valid T-SQL expression that **does not** contain **columns from other tables, local variables, aggregate functions, or subqueries**. It can be one or a combination of column name, constant, function, global variable, or case expression, connected by one or more operators. You cannot cross-reference between computed columns except when virtual computed columns reference materialize computed columns.</sub>

Comment: As a note: this is asked in an attempt to solve this Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467376/are-there-more-elegant-ways-of-querying-data-based-on-values-stored-in-attribute

Comment: if you are trying to solve another question you should have continued on that question with this idea.

Comment: @Jacobvdb - I was trying to avoid getting X-Y problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I've done that using `EXEC`

```
 SELECT @my_stmt = "ALTER TABLE #result ADD " + @param + " varchar(255) NULL" 
 EXEC(@my_stmt)
```